# Using php variable inside a wordpress page through admin interface

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress page in which i have a form(used machform which redirects & stores data in session) submitting it redirects to another wordpress page. Now i want to use session value in the second page. I am new to wordpress, can i use php tags inside a page through admin interface so that i can retrieve the session value?

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the [exec-php plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/)